# Two dimensional virtual desktop space in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, gnome, virtual-desktop, workspace

Is there any way to create a 2-dimensional virtual desktop space in Ubuntu?  The only control I'm seeing is the number of virtual desktops, but they seem to only go in a line.  I'm used to having a 2-dimensional space (so I can go up/down/left/right instead of just left/right), and I'd really like to have that in ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the default Gnome configuration in Ubuntu, you should have a "workspace switcher" panel applet in the bottom panel, on the right.  Right click, and select *Preferences*.  That will pull up a small dialog with *Columns* and *Rows*.

- *Columns* is the number of workspaces across.
- *Rows* is the number of workspaces down.

The total number of workspaces is *Columns* times *Rows*.  For example,

There are several other places you can set this, including in the CompizConfig Settings Manager (under *General Options*, on the *Desktop Size* tab).

Tips:
Go into *System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts* and set *"Switch to workspace above the current workspace"* to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.  Do the same for the other directions/arrow keys.

If you add multiple rows, you may want to increase the size of the bottom panel (right-click > *Preferences*) so the Workspace Switcher applet is decently usable.  (I found 36 pixels a reasonable size for 2 rows.)

Caveats:
If you've enabled the Compiz *Desktop Cube* instead of the *Desktop Wall*, only one row of workspaces can be accessed on the cube at a time.  To switch rows, use the Expo (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).

Comment: I tried using the Win key for setting other stuff, but it doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't seem to want to treat the win (super) key as a toggle.

Comment: @herms: i'm using it as a modifier key, like Ctrl or Shift or Alt.  so hold-win-while-pressing-E (to access Expo, for example).  my system calls that key "Mod4" in some places, "Super" in others.

Comment: Hm.  When I tried to set Win-L for lock it triggered as soon as I hit the Win key, and then any time I hit the win key after that it locked the window.  Though I just tried Win-E and it did do expo. Hmm.

Comment: Yea, just tried it.  In the Keyboard Shortcuts section when I select something to remap, as soon as I hit the win key it just puts "Super L" (for left win key) there, instead of letting me use it as a modifier.

Comment: @herms: hmm.  dunno.  have you enabled the "sticky keys" accessibility tool or something?  tried with the right win key instead?  maybe try Shift+Win+ArrowKey or Ctrl+Alt+ArrowKey or Shift+Ctrl+Alt+ArrowKey ...   btw, were you able to add another row with the workspace switcher preferences?

Comment: Don't have a right win key (Microsoft Natural keyboard).  Haven't touched any accessibility stuff.  I'll poke around some more.  Hoping I can find the file the settings are stored in so I can manually add it that way.  I did get the 2-dimensional stuff working.  Thanks!

Comment: @herms: actually, seems like the defaults for those workspace-switching keybindings are Ctrl+Alt+ArrowKey (just tested on a new Gnome user with fresh defaults).  i switched them to Win+ArrowKey since i use Ctrl+Alt+ArrowKey in VLC.

Comment: I filed a separate question about getting the win key to work, and I managed to get it working thanks to the answer there. http://superuser.com/questions/152367/where-does-ubuntu-store-keyboard-shortcut-settings/152381#152381

Comment: I usually use ctrl-alt-left and control-alt-right for 'Rotate Cube', ctrl-alt-down for 'Desktop Cube', and ctrl-alt-up for 'Scale'. I suggest you try it. It makes for a really nice workflow.