# Where does ubuntu store keyboard shortcut settings?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I'm having trouble setting a keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu.  Trying to use the win (super) key as a modifier, but as soon as I press the win key the keyboard shortcut UI just assumes I wanted to use just that key.

I figure the easiest thing would be to modify the settings file itself, where I should be able to put in whatever I want.  But I can't figure out where that's stored.  Does anyone know?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101226/where-does-ubuntu-store-its-keyboard-shortcut-configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My settings seem to be stored in Gconf.  You can access these in the *gconf-editor* under */apps/metacity/global_keybindings* or */apps/metacity/window_keybindings*.

These settings are stored in `$HOME/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/%gconf.xml` and `$HOME/.gconf/apps/metacity/window_keybindings/%gconf.xml`.  If you'll be changing the XML directly, I recommend logging out, making changes in a virtual terminal, and then logging back in.

Sample entries in my *gconf-editor* (changing them here should take effect immediately):

```
Default values:
Name                         Value
switch_to_workspace_down     <Ctrl><Alt>Down
switch_to_workspace_up       <Ctrl><Alt>Up

Modified values:
Name                         Value
switch_to_workspace_down     <Mod4>Down
switch_to_workspace_up       <Mod4>Up
```

Sample entries in my *global_keybindings* XML:

```
<gconf>
        <entry name="switch_to_workspace_down" mtime="1274412610" type="string">
                <stringvalue>&lt;Mod4&gt;Down</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="switch_to_workspace_up" mtime="1274412607" type="string">
                <stringvalue>&lt;Mod4&gt;Up</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="switch_to_workspace_right" mtime="1274412603" type="string">
                <stringvalue>&lt;Mod4&gt;Right</stringvalue>
        </entry>
        <entry name="switch_to_workspace_left" mtime="1274412594" type="string">
                <stringvalue>&lt;Mod4&gt;Left</stringvalue>
        </entry>
</gconf>
```

---

p.s.  I wonder if your troubles with the settings UI are caused by a specific driver or keyboard layout.  You might try setting or tweaking the layout or keyboard model used (*System > Preferences > Keyboard*, *Layouts* tab).  Also check the *Options* dialog on the same tab; there are some tweaks for the Alt/Win keys.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just used <Super> to reference the win key.  Now to figure out where the setting that makes the mouse scrollwheel change virtual desktops when the mouse is over the desktop is, and kill it.

Comment: @herms: i read about that one the other day when i was playing with Compiz settings, but i never noticed it being active on my system.  if you've intalled the CompizConfig Settings Manager, check the mouse bindings in there, particularly under the Viewport Switcher or Desktop Wall plugins.

Comment: Didn't realize compiz config had to be installed separately. That would explain why I can't find it. I'll go install that and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the package name is for the package the compiz config lives under?  I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: *compizconfig-settings-manager* is the package name; it should install a menu item in *System > Preferences* for it.

Comment: that section of gconf-editor and the xml files don't seem to contain configuration for the "Custom Shortcuts" of Ubuntu (user added commands). Any idea on where those are stored?